# Continuously play sampled audio data in Python

Tags: python, audio, buffer, audio-streaming

I am trying to pass the sampled/capture IQ data from my SDR through my Python FM demodulator.

Right now, the results I am getting is a continuous stuttering loops of short audio samples. I which to have it play continuously just like a normal FM radio.

Any recommendation on how I can make this work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import numpy as np
import scipy.signal as signal
from rtlsdr import RtlSdr
import sounddevice as sd

device_index = RtlSdr.get_device_index_by_serial('00000001')

class fmDemodulator(object):
    def __init__(self, sdr=None):
        self.sdr = sdr if sdr else RtlSdr(device_index)

    def demod(self, *args):
        Fs = self.sdr.sample_rate

        # Read IQ samples
        samples = self.sdr.read_samples(256*1024)
        print(samples)
        # Convert sampled data into numpy array
        x1 = np.array(samples).astype("complex64")

        # Downmixed Baseband Signal (Adjust offset to be centered)
        offsetFreq = 0    # already centered
        fc1 = np.exp(-1.0j*2.0*np.pi* offsetFreq/Fs*np.arange(len(x1)))  
        x2 = x1 * fc1  
        # Filter and downsample the FM Radio Signal
        bwFM = 200000   # approx. 170 kHz for a single channel
        decRate = int(Fs/bwFM)
        x3 = signal.decimate(x2, decRate)
        newFs = Fs/decRate
        ### Demodulate 200kHz FM Signal
        # Polar discriminator
        y4 = x3[1:] * np.conj(x3[:-1])  
        x4 = np.angle(y4)  
        # The de-emphasis filter
        # Given a signal 'x4' (in a numpy array) with sampling rate newFS
        d = newFs * 75e-6   # Calculate the # of samples to hit the -3dB point  
        x = np.exp(-1/d)   # Calculate the decay between each sample  
        b = [1-x]          # Create the filter coefficients  
        a = [1,-x]  
        x5 = signal.lfilter(b,a,x4)  

        # Find a decimation rate to achieve audio sampling rate between 44-48 kHz
        audioFreq = 44100.0  
        dec_audio = int(newFs/audioFreq)  
        audioFs = newFs/dec_audio
        print(audioFreq)
        x6 = signal.decimate(x5, dec_audio) 

        # Scale audio to adjust volume
        x6 *= 10000 / np.max(np.abs(x6))  

        return x6, audioFs

    def start(self):
        while True:
            x6, audioFs = self.demod()
            sd.play(x6, audioFs)

        return


def main():
    sdr = RtlSdr(device_index)
    fm = fmDemodulator(sdr)

    # SDR Configurations
    sdr.sample_rate = int(2.4e6)        # Hz
    sdr.center_freq = int(102e6)     # Hz
    sdr.freq_correction = 77            # PPM +- 20
    sdr.gain = 'auto'

    fm.start()

    # Clean up
    sdr.close()
    del(sdr)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `sd.play()` is not suitable for gapless playback. You should instead use the [`write()`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/api.html#sounddevice.Stream.write) method of an [`sd.OutputStream`](https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.12/api.html#sounddevice.OutputStream) or, probably even better, you should write your own callback function and use it with an `OutputStream`.

Comment: I seem to not be able to understand sounddevice and switching to PyAudio. Maybe I should also try to figure out how to stream the IQ sample first. I will post an update when I have any progress.

Comment: The `sounddevice` module can do the same as `PyAudio` can. It just has some *more* functions that seem to have distracted you. But you are of course free to choose whichever you want!

Comment: @Matthias Oh I have no idea on audio or even Python itself. Currently I can't seem to make it work. I guess I will keep trying and once settled will have a look at the sounddevice module!

Comment: any luck with this?